# How to merge multiple lines into required lines in VIM?

Tags: vim

I have file of below lines:

```
'Books',
'Business',
'Education',
'Entertainment',
'Finance',
'Games', 
'Healthcare & Fitness', 
'Lifestyle', 
'Medical', 
'Music'
```

I need format of below with 5 as input:

```
'Books','Business','Education','Entertainment','Finance',
'Games','Healthcare & Fitness','Lifestyle','Medical','Music'
```

Comment: Check [`:help :join`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3ajoin) -- e.g.: `1,5j | 2,6j`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your cursor is on first line, you do:

```
5gJj.
```

- `:h gJ` to know what it does.
- `j.` -> move to next line repeat last command (`5gJ`)

Comment: Hi I tried 1000gJj. for a set of 37000 lines, ideally i should have 37 lines of 1000 words, but I am seeing only 2 lines if 1000 each and remaining words as it is.

Comment: you didn't mention those requirement. If it worked with your 5-lines example, it works for 1000lines too. However if you are handling big files problem like that, I would either use vim macro or some other tools, like , awk, it would be very easy job for awk.

Comment: `qqqqq1000gJj@qq@q` for all 37000 lines in groups of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gelobal command

```
:g/^/normal 5J
```

Regardless the number of lines vim will join groups of five lines